# How do I get all supported resolutions of my video card in SDL2?

Tags: c++, video, sdl

I have to get these resolutions, so I can put them in the video options of the game I'm creating.

Answer (score 2):

From [SDL2 migration guide documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide), you simply iterate over

> "[SDL_GetDisplayMode()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetDisplayMode) in a loop, [SDL_GetNumDisplayModes()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetNumDisplayModes)
>   times"

to get the all available resolutions. How to interpret the display modes is laid out [here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_DisplayMode).